# Autolayout-handle seven buttons circular shape without affecting leading,trailing,vertical and horizontal spacing

Tags: ios, autolayout

This is my storyboard:

[image: I have this thing on my storyboard]

I have seven buttons on a Viewcontroller. I want to add contraints to it in such a way that if screen size increases, it automatically increases its height and width, and if screen size decreases then it automatically decreases its height and width without affecting leading, trailing, horizontal and vertical spacing.

I have tried doing this by fixing the height and width of buttons as this doesn't work without fixing, since the buttons are circular in shape and turns to diamond or some other shape if I do it without fixing height and width. What should I use so that the shape remains circular and height and width gets set automatically according to requirement?

Comment: please post the code or show us constraints you have added...May be then anyone can able to help you

Comment: I have cleared the constraints now...if you can just set two buttons and show how it can be set,then it would be helpful.

Comment: are the buttons are square? it must be if you want them round

Comment: yes they are square,i have added the image in question too

Comment: Have you tried using size classes? If not, it might be the best option for you.

Answer (score 0):

To make them round in size, try following

```
myButton.layer.cornerRadius = myButton.frame.size.width/2
muButtonlayer.masksToBounds = true
```

This will make your button round in every shape.
To Keep them square in every frame you should set aspect ratio constraint.
As all buttons are of same height width you must add equalHeight and equalWidth constraint by selecting all buttons in story board.

Answer (score 0):

Use multiplier if you want dynamic height width of buttons. 
Set button width equal to screen width and select this constraint and set multiplier 0.3. And check on Aspect ratio.

Look at attach images.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: What does this mean "Set button width equal to screen width "?

Comment: Set button width constraint equal to screen width.

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is specify the spacing between the buttons, and do *not* specify a fixed height or width. Each button should have a 1:1 aspect ratio, and equal width constraints if you intend to keep them all the same size.

The corner radius will have to be dynamically set as Dev_Tandel pointed out.

It's very similar to an earlier answer I made here:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/34294883/16785